# Suspending all threads took Time in AsynTask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, http-get

I am trying to get images (15 images) from server in Android using below code.

**Invoke AsynTask using below code:**

**DownloadImageSequencially lmib = new DownloadImageSequencially ();
Lmib.execute (SplitImages);**

Here **SplitImages** is array of image URLs.

```js
class DownloadImageSequencially extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for (int indx = 0; indx < SplitImages.length; indx++) {
                 downloadBitmap(SplitImages[indx],indx);
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            defailtReviewCardInitialisation();
            reviewCardActions();
    }

    private void downloadBitmap(String url,int indx) {
        // initilize the default HTTP client object

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //forming a HttoGet request
        url = url.replace("\\","");
        url = url.replace("\"","");
        Log.e("url","url: "+url);
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.e("Masthan1","Masthan1");
        //HttpPost getRequest = new HttpPost(url);
        try {

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            Log.e("Masthan2","Masthan2");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            Log.e("Masthan3","Masthan3");
            //check 200 OK for success
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.e("Masthan4","Masthan4");
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                        " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);

            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("Masthan5","Masthan5");
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    // getting contents from the stream
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    Log.e("Masthan6","Masthan6");
                    // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                    bitmapArray[indx] =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    Log.e("Masthan7","Masthan7");

                } finally {
                    Log.e("Masthan8","Masthan8");
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        Log.e("Masthan9","Masthan9");
                        inputStream.close();
                        Log.e("Masthan10", "Masthan10");
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                    Log.e("Masthan11", "Masthan11");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                    " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

**This is the logcat of Android.**

```js
12-26 15:54:16.641    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/tasty1.jpg
12-26 15:54:16.641    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:16.642    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:16.657    1108-1124/com.revu.revu E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabffce10
12-26 15:54:17.364    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:17.456    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:17.456    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:17.456    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:17.781    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2602(245KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 29MB/29MB, paused 3.732ms total 226.124ms
12-26 15:54:18.282    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:18.282    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:18.283    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:18.283    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:18.283    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:18.283    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/healthy2.jpg
12-26 15:54:18.284    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:18.284    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:19.622    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:19.622    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:19.622    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:19.622    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:20.178    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 32MB to 32MB
12-26 15:54:20.444    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.501ms
12-26 15:54:20.950    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.736ms
12-26 15:54:21.425    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:21.425    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:21.425    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:21.426    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:21.426    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:21.426    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/servedfresh3.jpg
12-26 15:54:21.426    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:21.426    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:21.720    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:21.720    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:21.720    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:21.720    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:21.724    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/valueformoney4.jpg
12-26 15:54:21.992    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 50.822ms
12-26 15:54:22.240    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:22.240    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:22.698    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:22.704    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:22.704    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:22.704    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:23.582    1108-1302/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-26 15:54:23.584    1108-1302/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-26 15:54:23.979    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 28.344ms
12-26 15:54:24.048    1108-1302/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.679ms
12-26 15:54:24.484    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.965ms
12-26 15:54:24.691    1108-1302/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 909(43KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 31MB/32MB, paused 24.234ms total 814.957ms
12-26 15:54:24.791    1108-1302/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Starting a blocking GC Alloc
12-26 15:54:24.939    1108-1302/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4731(408KB) AllocSpace objects, 33(23MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 3.352ms total 138.107ms
12-26 15:54:24.946    1108-1302/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.257ms
12-26 15:54:25.088    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 17.751ms
12-26 15:54:25.208    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21(800B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 11MB/11MB, paused 5.265ms total 255.262ms
12-26 15:54:25.464    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 15.615ms
12-26 15:54:25.478    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 138(40KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 11MB/13MB, paused 4.739ms total 113.458ms
12-26 15:54:25.969    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 27.841ms
12-26 15:54:26.323    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:26.323    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:26.323    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:26.323    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:26.323    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:26.324    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/menuitemsareavailable_5.png
12-26 15:54:26.324    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:26.324    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:26.515    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:26.516    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:26.516    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:26.516    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:27.083    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:27.084    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:27.084    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:27.084    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:27.364    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:27.364    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/qualityofitemssufficient_6.png
12-26 15:54:27.664    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:27.727    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:28.036    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:28.036    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:28.036    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:28.036    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:28.329    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 843(41KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 14MB/14MB, paused 3.906ms total 257.066ms
12-26 15:54:28.346    1108-1120/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.743ms
12-26 15:54:28.484    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.799ms
12-26 15:54:28.527    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 384(49KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 14MB/16MB, paused 4.480ms total 121.173ms
12-26 15:54:28.833    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:28.833    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:28.833    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:28.907    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:28.907    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:28.907    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/happywiththemenuplan_7.png
12-26 15:54:28.908    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:28.908    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:29.393    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:29.393    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:29.393    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:29.393    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:29.802    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:29.803    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:29.803    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:29.804    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:29.804    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:29.804    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/servesasperthescedule_8.png
12-26 15:54:29.804    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:29.804    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:31.052    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:31.052    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:31.052    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:31.052    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:31.346    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:31.346    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/serveshyginically_9.png
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:31.347    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:31.554    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 71.590ms
12-26 15:54:31.568    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 690(101KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 10% free, 17MB/19MB, paused 3.661ms total 219.596ms
12-26 15:54:31.931    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:31.931    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:31.932    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:31.932    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:32.092    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:32.093    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:32.094    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:32.094    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:32.094    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:32.173    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ishappytoserveme_10.png
12-26 15:54:32.173    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:32.173    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:32.834    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:32.834    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:32.834    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:32.916    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:33.021    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 33.575ms
12-26 15:54:33.060    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 421(21KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 19MB/19MB, paused 4.151ms total 126.092ms
12-26 15:54:33.349    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 336(83KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 19MB/21MB, paused 2.900ms total 229.586ms
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:33.483    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/approchableregardingmyconserns_11.png
12-26 15:54:33.484    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:33.484    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:33.512    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 11.051ms
12-26 15:54:34.084    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:34.084    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:34.146    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:34.147    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:34.428    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:34.429    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:34.429    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:34.429    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:34.429    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:34.429    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/behavesprofessional_12.png
12-26 15:54:34.430    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:34.430    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:35.129    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:35.129    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:35.129    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:35.129    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:35.258    1108-1120/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.540ms
12-26 15:54:35.558    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 47.962ms
12-26 15:54:35.656    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 363(48KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 22MB/24MB, paused 3.845ms total 387.375ms
12-26 15:54:35.663    1108-1120/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.837ms
12-26 15:54:35.770    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:35.770    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:35.770    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:35.770    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:35.770    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:35.771    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ismaintainedcleanly_13.png
12-26 15:54:35.772    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:35.773    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:36.046    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 26.053ms
12-26 15:54:37.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:37.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:37.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:37.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:37.579    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:37.579    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:37.579    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:37.579    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:37.579    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:37.580    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/islargeenufftofitmein_14.png
12-26 15:54:37.580    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:37.580    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:37.982    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:37.982    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:37.983    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:37.983    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:39.240    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 44.131ms
12-26 15:54:39.269    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 860(41KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 25MB/25MB, paused 19.100ms total 172.207ms
12-26 15:54:39.559    1108-1120/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 502(125KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 25MB/27MB, paused 2.951ms total 199.381ms
12-26 15:54:40.110    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:40.110    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:40.110    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:40.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:40.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-26 15:54:40.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://10.0.2.2:80/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ambienceisgoodforhavingfood_15.png
12-26 15:54:40.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-26 15:54:40.111    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-26 15:54:40.191    1108-1116/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 13.265ms
12-26 15:54:40.784    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-26 15:54:40.784    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-26 15:54:40.784    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-26 15:54:40.784    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-26 15:54:41.021    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-26 15:54:41.021    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-26 15:54:41.021    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-26 15:54:41.022    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-26 15:54:41.022    1108-1302/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
```

What I have observed is when we try to perform following actions in AsynTask it takes lot of time (at least 30 sec) even though I work at high speed internet or localhost.

1. Client.execute(getRequest);
2. Entity.getContent();

Please help me why is it taking time? You can also suggest me alternative methods if it performs good.

Comment: How big are the images?

Comment: Not more than 100 KB each image

Comment: I have tried as mentioned in link. But I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474603/android-images-are-not-getting-downloaded-very-slow

Answer (score 0):

you are using single asynctask thread to download multiple files.. so obviously it will take more time if the files count is high .. if you want to download multiple files simultaneously then try to use

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html](http://ExcecutorService)

refer here  :-  [java download multiple files using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502718/java-download-multiple-files-using-threads)

Comment: How can I apply Executor Service logic to AsyncTask. Please give me sample program...

Comment: refer here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: I have tried as mentioned in link. But I have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474603/android-images-are-not-getting-downloaded-very-slow