# Android Images are not getting downloaded (very slow)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, executorservice, java-threads

Actually here I am trying to download the multiple images from server, when I try to download images from localhost it wotks fine (within 3 sec images getting downloaded). But when I try to download it from actual server it is taking so long (atleast 15 sec) even though my internet connection is very fast. Total size of the images are not more than 600 kb.

```js
     pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(SplitImages.length);
     int length = 0;
     for (String name : SplitImages) {
      pool.submit(new DownloadImageSequencially(name,length));
      length = length+1;
     }

     pool.shutdown();
     try {
      if(!pool.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      {
       Log.e("TASKS NOT COMPLETED","TASKS NOT COMPLETED");
      }
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e)
     {
      Log.e("GONE","GONE");
     }
```

**Above code calls the AsyncTask Method below**

```js
 private class DownloadImageSequencially implements Runnable
 {
  private String name;
  private int indx;

  public DownloadImageSequencially(String name,int indx) {
   this.name = name;
   this.indx=indx;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // surround with try-catch if downloadFile() throws something
   downloadBitmap(name);
  }

  private void downloadBitmap(String url) {
   // initilize the default HTTP client object

   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

   //forming a HttoGet request
   url = url.replace("\\","");
   url = url.replace("\"","");
   Log.e("url","url: "+url);
   final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
   Log.e("Masthan1","Masthan1");
   //HttpPost getRequest = new HttpPost(url);
   try {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    Log.e("Masthan2","Masthan2");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    Log.e("Masthan3","Masthan3");
    //check 200 OK for success
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.e("Masthan4","Masthan4");
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
     Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
       " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);

    }

    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.e("Masthan5","Masthan5");
    if (entity != null) {
     InputStream inputStream = null;
     try {
      // getting contents from the stream
      inputStream = entity.getContent();
      Log.e("Masthan6","Masthan6");
      // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
      bitmapArray[indx] =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
      Log.e("Masthan7","Masthan7");

     } finally {
      Log.e("Masthan8","Masthan8");
      if (inputStream != null) {
       Log.e("Masthan9","Masthan9");
       inputStream.close();
       Log.e("Masthan10", "Masthan10");
      }
      entity.consumeContent();
      Log.e("Masthan11", "Masthan11");
     }
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
      " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
   }


  }

 }
```

Please help me why is it taking so long to download images

**Logcat:**

```js
12-27 00:54:59.387  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/approchableregardingmyconserns_11.png
12-27 00:54:59.387  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.388  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.390  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ambienceisgoodforhavingfood_15.png
12-27 00:54:59.390  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.390  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.393  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/islargeenufftofitmein_14.png
12-27 00:54:59.393  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.393  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.395  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ismaintainedcleanly_13.png
12-27 00:54:59.395  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.398  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/behavesprofessional_12.png
12-27 00:54:59.398  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.399  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.401  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/ishappytoserveme_10.png
12-27 00:54:59.401  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.401  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.403  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/serveshyginically_9.png
12-27 00:54:59.403  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.404  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.406  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/happywiththemenuplan_7.png
12-27 00:54:59.406  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.406  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.408  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/qualityofitemssufficient_6.png
12-27 00:54:59.408  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.409  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.412  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/menuitemsareavailable_5.png
12-27 00:54:59.412  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.412  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.424  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/valueformoney4.jpg
12-27 00:54:59.424  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.424  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.433  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/servedfresh3.jpg
12-27 00:54:59.433  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.433  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.438  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/healthy2.jpg
12-27 00:54:59.438  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.438  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.441  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/tasty1.jpg
12-27 00:54:59.441  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.441  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.466  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/url﹕ url: http://abcd.co.in/revue/Images/ReviewCard/Student/servesasperthescedule_8.png
12-27 00:54:59.466  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan1﹕ Masthan1
12-27 00:54:59.466  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.470  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan2﹕ Masthan2
12-27 00:54:59.492  10418-10429/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4667(360KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 2% free, 3MB/3MB, paused 5.438ms total 110.998ms
12-27 00:54:59.802  10418-10429/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1558(103KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 3MB/4MB, paused 8.296ms total 50.314ms
12-27 00:55:00.565  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:00.565  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:00.565  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:00.565  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:01.012  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:01.012  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:01.012  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:01.013  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:01.037  10418-10429/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 33(1504B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 5MB/5MB, paused 10.228ms total 22.445ms
12-27 00:55:01.292  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:01.292  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:01.292  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:01.293  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:02.054  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:02.054  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:02.054  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:02.054  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:02.869  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:02.869  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:02.869  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:02.870  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:03.322  10418-10425/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 37.251ms
12-27 00:55:03.333  10418-10429/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 194(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 10MB/12MB, paused 8.546ms total 42.975ms
12-27 00:55:04.052  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:04.052  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:04.052  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:04.053  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:05.073  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:05.096  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:05.097  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:05.097  10418-10474/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:06.095  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:06.095  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:06.095  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:06.105  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:06.105  10418-10478/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:06.295  10418-10425/com.revu.revu W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 21.464ms
12-27 00:55:06.721  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:06.721  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:06.722  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:06.722  10418-10475/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:06.771  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:06.771  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:06.771  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:06.771  10418-10488/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:06.810  10418-10429/com.revu.revu I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 83(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 16MB/16MB, paused 5.049ms total 33.838ms
12-27 00:55:06.828  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:06.828  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:06.828  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:06.829  10418-10476/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:07.323  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:07.323  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:07.323  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:07.330  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:07.330  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:07.330  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:07.330  10418-10486/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:07.333  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:07.334  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:07.334  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:07.334  10418-10481/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:07.339  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:07.339  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:07.339  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:07.339  10418-10482/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:07.342  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan3﹕ Masthan3
12-27 00:55:07.342  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan4﹕ Masthan4
12-27 00:55:07.342  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan5﹕ Masthan5
12-27 00:55:07.342  10418-10480/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:07.347  10418-10477/com.revu.revu E/Masthan6﹕ Masthan6
12-27 00:55:08.621  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:08.621  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:08.621  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:08.621  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:08.621  10418-10479/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:10.439  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:10.439  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:10.439  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:10.439  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:10.440  10418-10484/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:10.444  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:10.444  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:10.444  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:10.444  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:10.444  10418-10483/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:12.080  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:12.081  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:12.081  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:12.081  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:12.081  10418-10487/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:12.690  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan7﹕ Masthan7
12-27 00:55:12.690  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan8﹕ Masthan8
12-27 00:55:12.690  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan9﹕ Masthan9
12-27 00:55:12.691  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan10﹕ Masthan10
12-27 00:55:12.691  10418-10485/com.revu.revu E/Masthan11﹕ Masthan11
12-27 00:55:14.397  10418-10418/com.revu.revu E/TASKS NOT COMPLETED﹕ TASKS NOT COMPLETED
```

Comment: Unless you have any strong reasons against, I'd suggest to start using ImageLoading libraries instead, like Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: You should try volley instead of trying to fetch images by your own threads. It has much more attributes and more effective .http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/volley/request.html

Comment: If you do a manual download (e.g. with cURL or wget), does it take as long as when the code does it? On the server-side, are you able to run `tcpdump` so you can see what's actually going on?